# GCC cross compiler (for ARM micro) complains about 'non supported floating point ABI' at a function where no FP instruction is present

Tags: c, gcc, arm, microcontroller

I have followed the standard procedure to get my new Nucleo-F767ZI board from STMicroelectronics up and running. The procedure is as follows:

**STEP 1**

I downloaded the *SW4STM32 IDE* from AC6. This is an Eclipse-based IDE for programming the STM32 microcontroller series from STMicroelectronics.

**STEP 2**

I downloaded the latest *CubeMX* software from STMicroelectronics. CubeMX is a java-based tool in which you can configure a few basic settings for your microcontroller: clock speed, realtime-os, peripherals, ... . After that, CubeMX spits out a folder with a bunch of c-source files in it. That's basically your project to start from.

**STEP 3**

I open the *SW4STM32 IDE* and import the project that *CubeMX* just generated. I do not change or add any code. I just click the build button, hoping that the project will compile to an executable .bin file (and perhaps also a .elf file). This is where things go wrong.

**THE ERROR**

The compiler finds (or thinks that he finds) an error in the following function in the FreeRTOS file `portmacro.h`:

```
171     /* Generic helper function. */
172     __attribute__( ( always_inline ) ) static inline uint8_t ucPortCountLeadingZeros( uint32_t ulBitmap )
173     {
174         uint8_t ucReturn;
175         
176         __asm volatile ( "clz %0, %1" : "=r" ( ucReturn ) : "r" ( ulBitmap ) );
177         return ucReturn;
178     }
```

The error message I get from the compiler is:

> **line 173 :** sorry, unimplemented: Thumb-1 hard-float VFP ABI

Now there are several reasons why I don't understand this particular error message:

**>> Issue 1**

The first issue is about the location of the error. Line 173 is the line where the opening curly brace is located. Why on earth would an error message refer to that line?

**>> Issue 2**

Secondly, I do not understand why the error message mentions the hardware floating point unit on my microcontroller. I cannot see any floating point instruction in the `ucPortCountLeadingZeros(..)` function.

**>> Issue 3**

I have opened the GCC compiler settings in the Eclipse project. Just to take a look at the default settings. I do not change anything. Here are two screenshots:

[image]

[image]

The first screenshot shows that the following option is selected:

```
    Instruction set :   Thumb II
```

The second screenshot shows that the following options are given to GCC:

```
    -mfloat-abi=hard    # Inform GCC that this micro has a hardware floating point unit
    -mfpu=fpv5-d16      # The hardware floating point unit is double precision
    -mthumb             # ARM Thumb instruction set
```

So, what Thumb instruction set version is actually selected. Thumb I or Thumb II?

Please help me to find out why this generated project from CubeMX doesn't compile. I am very thankful for any tips and hints.

**EDIT :**

The complete set of options passed on to the GCC compiler (as visible in the second screenshot) is the following:

```
    -mthumb
    -mfloat-abi=hard
    -mfpu=fpv5-d16
    -D__weak="__attribute__((weak))"
    -D__packed="__attribute__((__packed__))"
    -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER
    -DSTM32F767xx
    -I../Inc
    -I../Drivers/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
    -I../Drivers/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
    -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM7/r0p1
    -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/include
    -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS
    -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include
    -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F7xx/Include
    -Os
    -g3
    -Wall
    -fmessage-length=0
    -ffunction-sections
    -c
    -fmessage-length=0
```

Comment: GCC usually says that for a pre-ARMv6T2 target like ARM7TDMI - is there a suitable `-mcpu` or `-march` in there anywhere?

Comment: You made a very good point there. Apparently there is no `-mcpu` option, nor a `-march` option given to GCC. That's indeed very strange. I don't understand why the default project generated by CubeMX (and imported in SW4STM32) skips that important compiler flag :-(

Comment: ARM indicates that CLZ is available as a 32-bit thumb instruction, only for ARMv6T2 and above. This would also indicate you are compiling for a wrong arch version.

Comment: Thank you very much Jean-Louis and Notlikethat for helping me :-)

Comment: To the person who downrated my question: please leave a comment with some basic explanation why you downrate this question. I'm willing to make the proper adjustments. Just downrating without leaving a comment doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Should probably have `-march=armv7e-m`. Not sure why they wouldn't include that in the generated config.

Comment: Hi @rjp , Jean-Louis Bonnaffe and Notlikethat for helping me out. The compilation works now like charm. I've posted an answer below with a step-by-step explanation. Of course, all the credit goes to the three of you. Please leave some short answer, so I can uprate and flag it with the nice green checkmark ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments below the question, the project generated by CubeMX did not specify the `-mcpu` option to the compiler. So one should manually add this option to the compiler, the linker and the assembler:

```
    -mcpu=cortex-m7
```

If you do that, it builds without trouble.

Adding the option to the compiler, linker and assembler is a bit tricky. I'll explain in detail how to do it.

---

**1. Adding the option to the compiler**

> Right-click on your project folder in the left window of Eclipse. Click on `Properties` in the pop-up window.

> In the properties window, select `C/C++ Build` > `Settings` on the left.

> Now you should see 3 options in the middle of the window: `MCU GCC Compiler`, `MCU GCC Linker` and `MCU GCC Assembler`. Click on the first one, and select `Miscellaneous`.

> You should see the `other flags` line. Add the following option to that line: `-mcpu=cortex-m7`.

---

**2. Adding the option to the assembler**

> In the same properties window, select `MCU GCC Assembler` > `General`.

> You should see the `Assembler flags` line. Add the option `-mcpu=cortex-m7` to that line.

---

**3. Adding the option to the linker**

> Again in the properties window, select `MCU GCC Linker`.

> You should see the `Command line pattern` line, with the following text in it:

```
    ${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}
```

> Add the option `-mcpu=cortex-m7` to that line.

---

After doing all that, both the compiler, the assembler and the linker know that you want to build for the Cortex-M7 architecture. It still bothers me a bit that CubeMX didn't put that by default in the configuration file of the generated project. But at least, we know the workaround now..

Many thanks to @Notlikethat, @Jean-Louis Bonnaffe and @rjp for bringing me to this solution with the useful comments :-)

Comment: FWIW, according to [this forum post](http://www.openstm32.org/forumthread3099), another workaround is to select a similar STM32F7 part which the IDE _does_ understand.

Comment: Thank you @Notlikethat , that's indeed a clever workaround :-)

Answer (score 1):

I already faced similar issue. The IDE has to be updated to support new board/chip. IAR workbench V7.50 does not support F767ZI, but V7.60 does.
SW4STM32 Update : "Help" >> "Check for updates..." then restart Eclipse;